# Can we say 'where did you visit'?

Tags: adverbs, relative

Can we say the following:
"Where did you visit?"

Where means 'in/at which place', so 'visit' should not precede 'in which place', but my native English-speaker colleague said ok, which baffles me.

Comment: As Barmar points out, "Where did you go?" is very common. You're missing the definition 'to what place/s'. To be fair, "Where did you visit?" sounds distinctly odd, as would 'To what places did you visit?"

Comment: "Here, where" is a preposition in a fused relative construction. The integrated relative equivalent would be the rather odd-sounding "To which place(s) did you visit?"

Comment: I still think 'where did you visit' is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To be strictly correct it should be "What places did you visit?", but "Where did you visit?" would not sound jarringly wrong in casual speech.

Comment: Alternatively, "Where did you go?" when the context is clear that you're discussing the visit(s).